# Android: проблема в Eclipce Debug

Tags: java, eclipse

В отладчике на HttpClient выдаёт ошибку

> `Source not found:
> The source attachment does not contain the source for the file ClassLoader.class. You can change the source attachment by clicking Change Attached Source below`

Подскажите, что делать? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Отладчик говорит, что он не может найти исходный код для того места, на котором сейчас находится точка выполнения программы. Надо добавить путь к исходникам httpclient в ClassPath в LaunchConfiguration.

Comment: А где находится LaunchConfiguration, искал не нашёл, подскажите, пожалуйста ?

Comment: Тогда бы проект вобще не компилировался.

Comment: без отладчика эмулятор запускается но моя функция которая возвращает string не срабатывает , а в отладчике на HttpClient ругается

Comment: Project -> Properties -> Run/Debug Settings -> New -> Java Application -> ClassPath.

Comment: в ClassPath у меня платформа Android 3.2 и моё приложение , что выбирать и что делать дальше ?